# Symfony2 Appending Choice Options To Query Builder

Tags: forms, symfony, query-builder

Is is possible to append additional choice options to a entity query builder in Symfony2.

Here is my code:

```
 $builder->add('ship_to','entity',array(
        'class' => 'WICCommonBundle:CustomOptions',
        'property' => 'option_value',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('co')
                ->where('co.account=?0')
                ->andWhere('co.option_field=?1')
                ->orderBy('co.option_value', 'ASC')
                ->setParameters(array(
                    $this->account,"ship_to",
                ));
        },
        'empty_value' => 'Select Ship To',
    ));
```

I need to append the following option, so that in the drop down box it appears last.

"New" => "Add New"

I tried to do it by adding this, but it did not work:

```
 'choices' => array(
            'New' => 'Add New'
        ),
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: create method in class which get data from repository, add your data and returns marged data.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go:

1) What mkjasinski said: create a factory method which combines the data with the final option, or

2) Add an event listener to the form builder which adds the extra option just before rendering the form, like this:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
    function(FormEvent $event) use($user, $factory){
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // get your form field
        $field = $form->get('ship_to')

        // ... alter the field so your data is added to it
    }
);
```